# could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: unix

I'm getting error as below when tried to install a software on ubuntu in VM.
I could download any software if i'm a root user. But i forget my password now. Is there any way to renew the password of the root without uninstalling. please help.

could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock -open (13:permission denied)
unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg) , are you root?

Comment: Consider moving this to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a peek at [This Link](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword/) there is but you need to boot into single user mode (it is possible, but if this is a virtual then you'll need access to the host machine. If you don't have access to the host machine then I'm afraid you're out of luck :|

Answer (score 1):

I assume your bootloader is Grub (likely, as you're using Ubuntu), so try pressing space (any key should work, even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) during bootup. Than, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the current boot entry, move the cursor to the end of the line which has `kernel` in it, and add `init=/bin/bash`. Press <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> and wait until shell prompt. Than, do a `mount -o remount,rw /`. Now you have a root account on a writable root partition. Do `passwd`, set the password, do `mount -o remount,ro /` and reboot. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple reboot works for it. Try it before using any other options.